# how about pdf with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, pdf-generation

I have to send to user a e-ticket. The e-ticket is information about event, schedule, row, place, barcode and other information.
I have two way:
1. Create html markup, fill all fields, generate pdf file from html and send user in mail attachments.
2. A desinger create template file in pdf format. And, I open it, fill information and send user.

I have never worked with pdf and I need to you advice.  What way is the simply and less wasteful (in sense of load of the server, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's more of a user flow / user experience question.  Do you want your page to trigger a PDF download, but keep the user on the page?  Do you want to display the PDF to the user in the browser?  Or do you want to email them the PDF?  (Note that the last option is not mutually exclusive of the first two, it can happen anyway if you want.)  They're all fairly equal options from a server-side-code perspective.

Comment: @David: Good  questions. Now, I have to only send to email. In the future, probably, display in the browser and nothing else.

Comment: If your choice is between saving rendered HTML as a PDF vs. filling in a template PDF file, I'd recommend the latter.  Rendering the HTML server-side is clunky and unintuitive, and it introduces another potential point of failure (differences in rendering engines, HTML isn't "printable-page-based" whereas PDF is, etc.).  A PDF template would generally be easier to maintain and probably easier for a graphic designer to maintain.  Just about any off-the-shelf .NET PDF library will allow you to interact with the file to write content to it.  Then attach to email or return to user as a stream.

Comment: Consider JasperReports together with a designer like iReport. It's very flexible and creating/modifying your ticket design is really easy - but you need to be willing to call a SOAP service from asp.net, and running the server requires some Java application server skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my experience, you have pros and cons in both solutions:

**Solution 1:**

PROS: once you find out a good library for making the HTML->PDF conversion, you have a pretty flexible solution, given that you just have to change your HTML markup (pretty simple operation) to obtain a new PDF layout.

CONS: the operation of converting HTML 2 PDF can be CPU consuming (depend on the size and complexity of your HTML markup) and you're gonna bind your solution to a 3rd party component

TIP: you could use http://www.html-to-pdf.net/

**Solution 2:**

PROS: it'll need very low resource to couple toghether the layout and the data you need to put on it; morever you'll only need a free library (iText.Net) that is considered to be the standard library to manipulate PDF documets.

CONS: it won't be that flexible, 'cause you need to modify both the pdf layout and the code to fill it, in order to have a new e-ticket.

**Conclusion**

So, if you are planning to hange the layout of your e-tickets very frequently, go with the first one, otherwise, I'd choose the second option.